# Strange identity in the proof of the Strong Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, law-of-large-numbers

[image]

Above is an extract from the proof of the strong law large of large numbers with finite fourth moment.

The $X_n$ are iidrv's with $\mathbb{E}(X_n)=\mu$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_n^4)<M$ for some constant $M$.

I really dont understand how $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_j^3)=\mathbb{E}(X_iX_jX_k^2)=\mathbb{E}(X_iX_jX_kX_l)=0$ holds. Why can you swap $X_k^2$ for $X_kX_l$? Why does $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_j^3)$ equal $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_jX_k^2)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the $X_i$ are independent, we have $E[X_i X_j X_k X_l] = E[X_i] E[X_j] E[X_k] E[X_l]$.  But all four factors on the right side equal $\mu$, which is 0.

Likewise, $E[X_i X_j X_k^2] = E[X_i] E[X_j] E[X_k^2]$.  But $E[X_i]$ and $E[X_j]$ are both 0.

Finally, $E[X_i X_j^3] = E[X_i] E[X_j^3]$.  But $E[X_i] = 0$.

So it isn't that there's some inherent reason why all three expectations should be equal to each other; it's just that, for slightly different reasons, they all happen to equal 0 (and therefore they happen to be equal to each other).  If $\mu$ were not zero, they very well might not be equal to each other.